# Scraping urls with !# in the link adress

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, hashbang

I am trying to scrape >https://www.britishhorseracing.com/>

Specifically, I want to scrapy the result pages like: https://www.britishhorseracing.com/racing/results/fixture-results/!#/2020/468

The endgoal would be to have a scrapy splash crawler, that crawls the site and scrapes the information from every webpage that matches the "rule"

This site uses java - if I use Splash via http://localhost:8050/ I can render the site normally - but using a scraper, the **!#** causes problems

If I run the spider in cmd, I get the following output:

```
2023-10-10 14:51:41 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-10-10 14:51:41 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-10-10 14:51:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.britishhorseracing.com/racing/results/fixture-results/?_escaped_fragment_=%2F2023%2F11284> (referer: None)
2023-10-10 14:51:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

with no data, because it seems the scraper tries to open the links as stated above, which leads to the wrong webpage (because of the "escaped fragment" part)

I have this code:

```
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class BhacrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bhacrawler'
    allowed_domains = ['www.britishhorseracing.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.britishhorseracing.com/racing/results/fixture-results/#!/2023/11284']
    USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'
    script = '''
    function main(splash, args)
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        assert(splash:wait(15))
        return {html=splash:html()}
    end
    '''
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow=('racing/results/fixture-results/!#', )),
            callback='parse_race_details',
            follow=True,
        ),
    )


    def parse_race_details(self, response):

        print(response.text)

        title_text = response.xpath('//title/text()').get()
        print(title_text)
        track = title_text.split('/')[0].strip()

        date_match = re.search(r"(\w+) (\d{2}) (\w+) '(\d{2})", title_text)

        if date_match:
            day = date_match.group(2)
            month_name = date_match.group(3)
            year_short = date_match.group(4)

            # Umwandeln von Monatsname in Monatsnummer
            month_num = {
                'Jan': '01', 'Feb': '02', 'Mar': '03', 'Apr': '04',
                'May': '05', 'Jun': '06', 'Jul': '07', 'Aug': '08',
                'Sep': '09', 'Oct': '10', 'Nov': '11', 'Dec': '12'
            }.get(month_name, '01')  # Default zu Januar, falls nicht gefunden

            formatted_date = f"20{year_short}-{month_num}-{day}"  # "2023-10-03"
        else:
            formatted_date = None

        # Extract the part of the Going Stick text
        going_stick_text_full = response.xpath(
            '//p[@class="meta-entry ng-scope" and contains(.,"Going Stick")]/span[@class="entry-body ng-binding"]/text()'
        ).get()
        going_stick_value = re.search(r"Going Stick (\d+\.\d+)", going_stick_text_full).group(1) if going_stick_text_full else None
        print(going_stick_text_full)
        race_changes = response.xpath(
            '//li[@class="category ng-scope"]/p[@class="meta-entry ng-scope" and @ng-if="race.distanceChange"]/span[@class="entry-body ng-binding"]'
        ).getall()
        print(race_changes)
        # Extract time, added yards and final distance
        race_data = []
        for idx, change in enumerate(race_changes):
            time_match = re.search(r"<strong class=\"ng-binding\">(\d+:\d+[apm]*)", change)
            time = time_match.group(1) if time_match else None
            try:
                time  = time.strip('pm')
            except:
                pass

            added_yards_match = re.search(r"\+(\d+y)", change)
            added_yards = added_yards_match.group(1) if added_yards_match else None
            try:
                added_yards = added_yards.strip('y')
                added_meters = int(added_yards) * 0.9144
            except:
                added_meters = 0


            final_distance_match = re.search(r"to (.+)<", change)
            final_distance = final_distance_match.group(1) if final_distance_match else None

            #regex suchfilter
            regex1 = re.search(r'\d{1,}(?=y)', final_distance)
            regex2 = re.search(r'\d{1,}(?=f)', final_distance)
            regex3 = re.search(r'\d{1,}(?=m)', final_distance)

            if not regex1:
                yards = 0
            else:
                yardstometers = 0.9144
                regex1 = regex1.group()
                regex1 = int(regex1)
                yards = regex1 * yardstometers
            if not regex2:
                furlong = 0
            else:
                furlongtometers = 201.168
                regex2 = regex2.group()
                regex2 = int(regex2)
                furlong = regex2 * furlongtometers
            if not regex3:
                miles = 0
            else:
                milestometers = 1609.34
                regex3 = regex3.group()
                regex3 = int(regex3)
                miles = regex3 * milestometers

            distancefinal = round(yards + miles + furlong, 1)


            yield {
                'url': response.url,
                'track': track,
                'date': formatted_date,
                'Going Stick': going_stick_value,
                'Race time': time,
                'added_yards': added_meters,
                'final_distance': distancefinal,
            }
```

I assume the !X in the link is causing problems, any ideas how to circumvent the "#!" ?
It seems scrapy just runs into an error page because it "escapes" the part of the url

How can I handle "hashbangs" in a url?